# Use CMD parameters in distroless image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-java, distroless

I am using azul/zulu-openjdk-distroless:17.0.6 image and want to execute the java command with parameters but it fails at the runtime

Here is my docker image:

```
FROM alpine:3.17.3 as build-env

ARG DATADOG_VERSION=1.8.3

RUN wget https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/releases/download/v${DATADOG_VERSION}/dd-java-agent-${DATADOG_VERSION}.jar

FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-distroless:17.0.6

COPY --from=build-env dd-java-agent-*.jar javaagent.jar
COPY *-app/target/*.jar app.jar
ARG JAVA_AGENT="-javaagent:javaagent.jar"

CMD ["${JAVA_AGENT}", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ${JAVA_AGENT}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${JAVA_AGENT}
```

I tried with `ENV` instead of `ARG` and `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`, none of them worked. I tried without the `[]` brackets but then I get another error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

If I put the value directly like CMD `["-javaagent:javaagent.jar", "-jar", "app.jar"]` then it works but the container runs in a pipeline where the variable's value is coming from so I want to use variable. I would also use another one for JAVA_OPTS which is much harder to hardcode.

Is there any possibility to solve it somehow or the only solution is to hardcode the parameters?

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work for "reasons": https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 17 supports a [`JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-the-jdk_java_options-launcher-environment-variable) to supply additional command-line options to the JVM.  If you set this as an environment variable, you can override it when you run the image, and Dockerfile [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) to set it does do basic [environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).

```bash
ARG JAVA_AGENT="-javaagent:javaagent.jar"
ENV JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_AGENT"
CMD ["-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Note that `docker run -e JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=...` and other similar settings complely replace the preëxisting value of this variable, so you'd have to repeat the `-javaagent:...` option.

---

There are two forms of `CMD` (and `ENTRYPOINT` and `RUN`).  [Exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) uses the JSON-array syntax, but never does any sort of variable expansion or other processing; the list of strings in the JSON array is used directly as the list of words making up the command and its arguments.  [Shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) takes any string but is run through `/bin/sh -c`, and that shell does the expansion.  If you have [both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) then both parts are separately wrapped in `sh -c` if required, then combined together into a single command line.

This combination of things puts several non-obvious restrictions on variable expansion.  In your case, **variable expansion requires a shell**; Docker on its own does not replace environment variables in `CMD` at all.  Since your distroless image doesn't contain a shell, this won't work.

The other implication of this rule is that, if you are using a shell-form `CMD` to do variable expansion, it must be a complete shell command.  In your case it looks like the base image declares a `ENTRYPOINT ["java"]`; if you try to use a shell-form `CMD` then the container will run `java sh -c '...'` which will produce an unusual error (admittedly, not the one you're actually seeing).

If you're passing this parameter as a command-line option in a distroless image, you *have* to hard-code it in the `CMD`.  You might be able to `COPY` a non-fixed file into `javaagent.jar`, so the filename will be fixed and the command-line option can be constant, but the contents of the file may not be.